# Cannot open NCBI web site from Ubuntu 14.04 desktop?

Tags: 14.04

Previously, I used my internal LAN via Windows 7 to browse [NCBI](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) and this worked.

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04, most of the websites opens fine except [NCBI](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/); when I try it always shows "problem with download web page" and in the middle of the page it shows "Server not found".

My major is biology and I use this site a lot but I am new at Ubuntu.

Could anyone give me some tips about how to fix this problem?

Comment: Seems to work for me on 14.04. What web browser are you using? Did you install any plug-ins?  Does it work now? (it could have been a problem at the web site itself...)

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps and it might help

Restart your computer

restart your internet router and all wifi routers in between

clear cache of your browser

goto any direct link for ncbi website (google for: disease+ncbi )